# Highlight our own comments, too

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, user-interface

Now that you highlight comment-responses from the user who asked the question, I would like **each user to see *their own* comments highlighted** the same style that **their own answers are already highlighted**.

[Reasons "borrowed" from your [recent blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/)]

**Why highlight a user's own comments?**

- It’s visually consistent. It carries the “highlight” from their own answers to their comments (a user's own answers were always highlighted in another color).
- It makes it easier to scan a post for their own comments because they are highlighted. This is important if they're trying to followup on a post or comment because they can visual see where they have made additional contributions.
- Users can "at a glance" tell if they're dealing with interested (other comments around *their* comments) or disinterested (no comments at all) to their contributions.

It would helpful for *me* to follow up on posts if I could easily spot where I have already made contributions so I can followup with changes to the post or any further comments directed at me.

[image]

Comment: My answers don't appear to be highlighted - the only visual distinction is the additional 'edit' and 'delete' options.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your answers are not highlighted on this site (meta). Check out one of the other sites. Your answers should look like the screen shot above.

Comment: Your answers are only highlighted if you're answering your own question.

Comment: What about on a Beta site?

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a discussion on one of your answers.  There's be your comments, the OP's comments, maybe some third parties chipping in.  Technicolour madness!

Comment: I love it! Alternately, they could all be pastel shades - long, angry discussions would be increasingly calming...

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a greasemonkey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34836/greasemonkey-highlight-your-username-in-red-wherever-it-appears-find-your-own-p) that highlights all of your posts, making them much easier to find. :D