# Highlight comments from answer author, in addition to question author

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, highlighting

In addition to the highlighting comments made by the question owner (as described [in a recent blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/)), I think it would be a good idea to highlight comments left by the author of the answer being commented on.

This way, the conversation between asker and answerer is more defined/obvious.

**Edit:** This is an edit to bring this to the site owners attention again - It would help people like me with bad eyesight to track down their comments. I originally opposed the questioner highlighting, but experience has shown me that I was wrong, and I think that answerer highlighting of comments would be very useful.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16648/highlight-our-own-comments-too

Comment: @random: that question asks that our own comments be highlighted, whereas mine is asking that there be highlighting for the user who left the answer. I sort of like the idea of highlighting your own comments, but it's a separate question. I think the benefit of answer-owner-highlighting is that you can more clearly understand the answerers intent, and can ignore superfluous comments from others if you wish.

Comment: I also notice the official answer to that other question is 'no, make a greasemonkey script" and I'd accept that for this question too. In my mind, my suggestion seems a bit more useful since I don't much care about what I said in comments, but I do like to understand the authors frame of reference for a given answer.

Comment: So much highlighting makes it way too busy/noisy.

Comment: The OP is only requesting that two names be highlighted, max. That doesn't sound too bad.

Comment: I've made a userscript for this. You can see it at StackApps http://stackapps.com/questions/5075/answerer-name-comment-highlighter

Comment: @Tim (might not be worth an answer; but till then, you can use my userscript :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Post it and I'll give you half the bounty!

Comment: An example of where highlighting the answer author is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283472/command-to-remove-all-npm-modules-globally#comment61617117_9283646

Answer (score 9):

This really should be reconsidered, there are (alt least) 2 dupes of this, all with a positive score - it's obvious a lot of people would like this feature!

Till then though, here's a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/5075/answerer-name-comment-highlighter) to highlight answerer comments:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Highlight answerer's comments
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%B9%A7%D0%BD%CA%8A%C3%9F
// @version      0.2
// @description  Highlight's the names of answerer's on SE websites
// @author       ṧнʊß (http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%B9%A7%D0%BD%CA%8A%C3%9F)
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function colorAnswerer() {
    $('.answercell').each(function(x, obj) {
        var x = $(this).find('.user-details a').text();
        $('.answer .comment-user').each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).text() == x) { 
                $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
            }
        });        
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.comments').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
        if (event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted' || event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted') {
            colorAnswerer();
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

***Note***: This may not the most up-to-date version - please install my [SE Optional Features userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features) for the latest version.

Comment: There's the whole bounty :)

Comment: Great functonality, but the color... the color...

Comment: lol - any suggestions for the colour? I'd be happy to change it! I admit it's not great! :/ @JanDvorak

Answer (score 1):

I'll post here [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370559/9638388) to the same question I made on Stack Overflow Meta.
It's the same userscript posted here, but I fixed and changed some things:

- It also works when the answer is edited by someone else.
- It highlights the comments from the author of the answer only on that answer, not on other answers.
- It **uses the same color** as the questioner highlighting, to match the theme of the site.
- It **uses an outline**, instead of coloring the whole background, so you can differentiate this highlight from the one for author of the question.
- The outline around the user is **drawn in the answer too**, to visually make it clear that the outline in the comments means that it is the same user who gave the answer.

Here's how it looks on Stack Overflow (you can also try dashed and dotted styles for the outline, if you want).

> [image: Comment from authors highlighted in answer]

Note how you can easily distinguish between the questioner (filled), the answerer (outline) and other users (no highlight) in the comments.

Userscript code from the [linked answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370559/9638388):

```js
// Using jQuery

function colorAnswerer() {
  let co = $('.post-signature.owner').css('background-color');
  let aa = $('.answercell');
  aa.each(function() {
    var as = $(this).find('.user-details a')
    var a = as.last();
    var b = as.filter(i => i < as.length - 1);
    var l = '2px solid'; // can also try dashed and dotted
    a.parents('.post-signature').css('border', l + ' ' + co);
    b.parents('.post-signature').css('border', '2px solid transparent');
    var x = a.text();
    var cm = $('.comment-user', this.parentNode)
    cm.each(function(i) {
      if ($(this).text() == x) {
        $(this).css('border', l + ' ' + co);
      }
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.comments').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted' || event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted') {
      colorAnswerer();
    }
  });
});

colorAnswerer();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

> This way, the conversation between asker and answerer is more
>   defined/obvious.

If you used the same colour (currently blue) then both answer author and question author's usernames in comments would be blue, how would this help differentiate between the two?
It would differentiate Q author and A author from all other users, but I don't see any real advantage here.

So this would only work if we used two different colours, one for question author and one for answer author (when commenting on their answer).
And then it would be too colourful imo. Having too much "highlighted" stops the highlighted bits from actually being highlighted, as it all just blends in with all the other highlighted things.

---

Comments are not really for extended discussions, and while they do happen it's *mostly* comments under the question, where this proposal wouldn't make a difference.

If you are reading comments it's not hard to follow the conversation between one user and another. Especially as "generally" there are only a few comments to read under answers.

Comment: There really isn't that much highlighting! It really *doesn't* detract the effect of the highlighting. Use [my userscript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252153/260841) for *a day* and you'll see for yourself! ;) You'll find it helpful... :P

Comment: If there's not that much highlighting then what's the point :p

Comment: You could argue the same about OP highlighting - what's the point? The fact is it *does* make it easier, either consciously or subconsciously, it makes a difference.

Comment: OP highlighting is useful because OP is the main character as they're discussing the various points and requirements of the question, to get it answered. After that, comments and conversations are (should be) minimal, and so highlighting is barely worth the effort to implement it, fix bugs etc. Just my opinion. Perhaps you've found it useful as per your scripty-whatsit.

Comment: Maybe. However, I don't *think* it would be that hard to implement, not too much effort, but that's SE's choice - not ours! :)