# Make comments from original poster stand out. Use different background color

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, design

Make comments from original poster stand out. Use different light background color than white. Like what happens with accepted answers.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19574/highlight-comments-from-answer-author-in-addition-to-question-author  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16648/highlight-our-own-comments-too

Answer (score 9):

The poster's name already appears in a different style.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree. There are already too many colored backgrounds on questions. There's a background for the OP's question signature, for signatures on any answers the OP posted, and for any comments the OP might have authored. And also for tags.

It's all just *too much*. I'd rather see more superfluous lines and boxes.

Comment: Oooh - rounded corners! rounded corners!

Comment: Freehand circles around OP's comments!  Freehand circles!

Comment: Um...Philosophy! If the circles are generated programticly, are they still freehand?

Comment: Maybe you could crowdsource the drawing of the freehand circles, a little like re-captcha?

Comment: @David: Now we're cooking with gas, my friend. That is a very soul of **The American Can Do Spirit**! Which I note that we have out sourced to a bunch of Kiwis.  ::sigh::

Comment: Simply put OP next to all applicable paraphernalia. Problem solved. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184196/would-it-be-feasible-to-have-the-op-highlighted-in-comments-and-answers?noredirect=1#comment562805_184196).