# Greasemonkey: highlight your username in red wherever it appears (find your own posts more easily)

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, display-names, userscript

### [Install it on userscripts here](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/65919)

The posts of the person who asked the question are highlighted in blue, so why can't our own posts be highlighted? It makes finding my stuff *much* easier. Highlights anything that links to your user-profile (comments, answers, etc.)

any and all feedback or suggestions welcome!

source:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Highlight your username on SOFU
// @namespace      CrazyJugglerDrummer
// @description    highlights wherever your username appears on the page
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/*
// @include        http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var userLink = document.getElementById("hlinks-user").getElementsByTagName("a")[1].href;

var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var x=0; x<links.length; x++) {
    if ( links[x].href == userLink ) {
        links[x].style.color = "#f00"; 
        links[x].style.backgroundColor="#fcc";
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. My Question Dashboard http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31486/question-dashboard-greasemonkey-script script may be a nice compliment to yours - one feature, among others, is the indicator "Me" which appears if an Answer, Question or Comment of yours exists on the current page.

Comment: can this please be moved to http://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts as necessary? Or flag for deletion.

Comment: Just one change; `var userLink = document.getElementById("hlinks-user").getElementsByTagName("a")[1].href;` highlights reputation. Changing the 1 to a 0, though, highlights the username. Cheers!

Comment: This is now implemented by default but +1 for the actual idea! Unfortunately though this is now off-topic; it *would* belong on StackApps, but it being natively supported means it wouldn't be too useful anymore! :) I've voted to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love this idea.

I submitted it as a feature-request a few months ago: [Highlight our own comments, too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16648/highlight-our-own-comments-too).

Vote it up. I would love to see it implemented natively.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for the script and for the request to implement this natively :)

It apparently doesn't work anymore (`hlinks-user` doesn't exist anymore).

I have modified the script as follows (it highlights the whole post/comment, only tested in Chrome)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Highlight your username on SOFU
// @namespace      CrazyJugglerDrummer
// @description    highlights wherever your username appears on the page
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/*
// @include        http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @require        https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

// The main content of this userscript
function main() {
    var HighlightUserPosts = function(){
        jQ("a[href='"+userLink+"']").each(function(){
          jQ(jQ(this).parents('tr.comment, div.question > table > tbody > tr, div.answer > table > tbody > tr')[0]).css('background-color','#efe');
        });
    }

    var userLink = jQ('a.profile-me').attr('href');
    HighlightUserPosts();
    setTimeout(HighlightUserPosts, 2500); // Fire again after SOFU's highlight fades away
}

// Load jQuery and execute the main function
window.jQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
main();
```