# When I hover over a comment, please change the background color of its parent post and all replies

Tags: feature-request, comments, design

Problem:

When a post has dozens of comments (like [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post#37123) does), it can be hard to tell which comment is a reply to which.

My proposed solution:

**When I hover my mouse over a comment, please change the background color of its parent post and all replies,** something similar to what we have already in chat.

I suggest a very pale yellow, since black on pale yellow is a nice, high-contrast combination.

(There was another proposed solution. I prefer it, but it was declined, and I don't know why. That proposed solution was: ["Let's make it easier to reply within comments"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments).)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16648/266359

Comment: In other words, something similar to what we have in chat?

Comment: While this would be awesome, I fear it's simply not technically possible as the answer already explains. Those are just comments, so bottom line no big deal, we can manage without it. (my opinion)

Comment: Related on verge of dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70250/why-dont-username-tags-get-highlighted-or-redirected

Answer (score 3):

That might be possible if comments were threaded, but they're not. They're flatbread.

Even though you can [reply to a certain other comment user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), there is no explicit threading.

Since you don't have parent→child comment bloodlines, you can't say which comment is related to which, if any.

And then there are times when [comments try to claim two parents](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231940/multiple-comment-notifications-how-is-it-possible), but that custody battle is for family court.

Comment: Dear all: What would be a better solution to the problem?

Comment: How about this?: The site should guess which comment is related to which. If it is confident in its guess, it should offer highlighting. If not, it shouldn't highlight anything at all.

Comment: How do you determine how confidence is ranked? And if it doesn't offer highlighting you can or cannot then infer it's not confident at all. In which case the feature is already here.

Comment: If the situation is totally unambiguous, then the site should offer highlighting. If there's even the slightest bit of ambiguity, it should not highlight anything when you hover over a comment.